# Class constant not accepted by php 5.4

Tags: php, static-members, class-constants

I have a class constant

```
const DATE_REGEX = '@^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$@';
```

which I want to use in a static array as part of a string:

```
public static $rules = [
    'startdate' => ['required','regex:' . self::DATE_REGEX],
];
```

Both of those lines are part of the same class.

On my dev machine (PHP 5.6) this works fine, but on the staging server (PHP 5.4) this throws the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'
```

How can I rewrite this to be PHP 5.4 compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP 5,4 does not allow for expressions in the class properties declaration.

Such feature has been introduced by PHP 5.6 http://php.net/migration56.new-features#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs

Comment: To further this point. PHP 5.6 does allow for this kind of initialization.

Comment: as described here: http://php.net/migration56.new-features#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs

Comment: Ok. I thought this was introduced in 5.3 for some reason.